# JsonSluper and JsonOutput convert some symbols in string to strange characters

Tags: java, json, groovy, jsonslurper

I am using a groovy script to convert some of the values in the body to their primitive datatype. To achieve this I am using JsonSluper and JsonOutput.
JsonSluper and JsonOutput are converting some symbols in string from my json body to strange characters. Any suggestions how this can be fixed ?

> Example:  "UnitPrice": "99¢ per lb." is converted to "UnitPrice":
> "99\u00a2 per lb."
>
> ¢ is converted to \u00a2

My script:

```
def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String);
    def JSONInput = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body);
    
    JSONInput.data.ProductStorePrices.each{
        if(it.Price != null){
            it.Price = it.Price.toDouble();
        }
        if(it.Active != null){
            it.Active = it.Active.toBoolean();
        }
    }
message.setBody(JsonOutput.toJson(JSONInput))
```

Below is my JSONBody before conversion:

```
{
    "data": {
        "ProductStorePrices": [
            {
                "Product_LegacyID": "1005",
                "Store_LegacyStoreID": "2",
                "DistributionCenter_LegacyRegionID": "916",
                "PriceType_Code": "unadjustedRetail",
                "ValidFrom": "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "Price": "9.99",
                "ValidTo": "2022-05-04T23:59:59Z",
                "Currency": "USD",
                "Active": "false",
                "UnitPrice": "99¢ per lb.",
                "LastChangedAt": "2022-05-04T23:59:59Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My output JSONBody after conversion using groovy script above

```
{
    "data": {
        "ProductStorePrices": [
            {
                "Product_LegacyID": "1005",
                "Store_LegacyStoreID": "2",
                "DistributionCenter_LegacyRegionID": "916",
                "PriceType_Code": "unadjustedRetail",
                "ValidFrom": "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "Price": 9.99,
                "ValidTo": "2022-05-04T23:59:59Z",
                "Currency": "USD",
                "Active": false,
                "UnitPrice": "99\u00a2 per lb.",
                "LastChangedAt": "2022-05-04T23:59:59Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the result not compliant JSON?  Did you try reading it back in and see if those characters were decoded properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange symbols, it's unicode.
I'm using the library **com.google.code.gson**
for these purposes.
Try this:

```
def gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
def json = gson.toJson(JSONInput)
println(json)
```

Output:
`{"data":{"ProductStorePrices":[{"Active":false,"Currency":"USD","DistributionCenter_LegacyRegionID":"916","LastChangedAt":"2022-05-04T23:59:59Z","Price":9.99,"PriceType_Code":"unadjustedRetail","Product_LegacyID":"1005","Store_LegacyStoreID":"2","UnitPrice":"99¢ per lb.","ValidFrom":"2000-01-01T00:00:00Z","ValidTo":"2022-05-04T23:59:59Z"}]}}`